How to render the HTML contained in the ag-grid cell data
I have some data that contains <p> paragraphs.
I created a custom cellRenderer that shows the data inside a <div> tag but the <p> and </p> show as text.
How can I make the <p> tags as HTML?

I found what will do it.
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.value }} />

That why all tags in the cell data are treated as HTML rather then text
Thank you.

If you want to use HTML markup in your cell, you will need to use a cell renderer component or just use a inline function for your cell renderer:
columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'myfield',
            cellRenderer: params => {
                return '<p>' + params.value + '</p>';
            }
        }
    ],

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/
If you are using a cell renderer component, make sure that you bind your cell value to the innerHtml property in order to display HTML content:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
